# RV042G VPN network drive mapping and RDC

Tags: cisco, router, vpn, ipsec

I'm trying to figure out if I can use the Cisco RV042G router for VPN access to our Windows domain (Server 2016). I would like to achieve the following:

- Logging on to the VPN from home workstations using domain credentials (preferably through a client similar to AnyConnect)
- Upon logon, the same network drives that have access to when at the workplace are mapped on the home workstation (and preferably disconnected again after VPN session is closed)
- The domain administrator can use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to the Domain Controller for remote administration

Does anyone here have any experience with this or knowledge on whether or not this is doable?

Should I aim for another VPN unit than the RV042G to achieve the above mentioned?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According the the [specifications](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/rv042g-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/index.html), that router has VPN capabilities:

> ## Features and Capabilities
>
> ---
>
> The Cisco RV042G Dual Gigabit WAN Router includes:
>
> - Dual Gigabit Ethernet WAN ports for load balancing and business    continuity
> - Built-in 4-port Gigabit Ethernet switch
> - Strong security: Proven stateful packet inspection (SPI) firewall and    hardware encryption
> - High capacity, high-performance, IP Security (IPsec) VPN capabilities
> - Intuitive, browser-based device manager and setup wizards.

Whether or not your home users can use AD, drives, etc. is off-topic here because that involves protocols above OSI layer-4, which are explicitly off-topic here, but you can ask about that for a business network on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).